# How to calculate all rows in a GridView in a single button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView in which I'm letting users edit previously generated estimates. Everything works fine till I hit recalculate button but after that, all the row values go haywire.

Below is a screenshot of the layout for your reference.
[image]

In that, All the details are being fetched from database and few of them are editable and after changing the values, below there is a refresh button which I'm using to recalculate. but my loop is causing them to calculate incorrectly. Please help me rectify my mistake.

below is my aspx code:

```
<div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <asp:GridView ID="grdPurchaseBill" runat="server" CssClass="table table-bordered table-responsive table-sm" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="false">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ControlStyle-Width="100%" ItemStyle-Width="100%">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtProduct" runat="server" CssClass="form-control form-control-sm" Width="100%" Style="width: 100%;" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" autocomplete="off" Text='<%# Eval("product") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Weight" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtWeight" runat="server" CssClass="form-control form-control-sm" Text='<%# Eval("weight") %>' Width="100%" Style="width: 100%;"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="# of Bags" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ControlStyle-Width="100%" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtBags" runat="server" CssClass="form-control form-control-sm" Text='<%# Eval("bags") %>' Width="100%" Style="width: 100%;"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Shortage %" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ControlStyle-Width="100%" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtShortagePercent" runat="server" CssClass="form-control form-control-sm" Text='<%# Eval("shortage_percent") %>' Width="100%" Style="width: 100%;"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Shortage" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ControlStyle-Width="100%" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtShortage" runat="server" CssClass="form-control form-control-sm" Text='<%# Eval("shortage") %>' Width="100%" Style="width: 100%;" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Net Weight" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ControlStyle-Width="100%" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtNetWeight" runat="server" CssClass="form-control form-control-sm" Text='<%# Eval("net_weight") %>' Width="100%" Style="width: 100%;" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Unit Price" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" ControlStyle-Width="100%">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtRate" runat="server" CssClass="form-control form-control-sm" Text='<%# Eval("rate") %>' Width="100%" Style="width: 100%;"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sub-Total" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" ControlStyle-Width="100%">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSubTotal" runat="server" CssClass="form-control form-control-sm" Text='<%# Eval("sub_total") %>' Width="100%" Style="width: 100%;" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hamali %" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" ControlStyle-Width="100%">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtHamali" runat="server" CssClass="form-control form-control-sm" Text='<%# Eval("hamali_percent") %>' Width="100%" Style="width: 100%;"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hamali Amt" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" ControlStyle-Width="100%">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtHamaliAmount" runat="server" CssClass="form-control form-control-sm" Text='<%# Eval("hamali") %>' Width="100%" Style="width: 100%;" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Driver Comm. " ItemStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" ControlStyle-Width="100%">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDriverCommission" runat="server" CssClass="form-control form-control-sm" Text='<%# Eval("driver_commission") %>' Width="100%" Style="width: 100%;"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Net Amt" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ControlStyle-Width="100%" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtNetAmount" runat="server" CssClass="form-control form-control-sm" Enabled="false" Text='<%# Eval("net_amount") %>' Width="100%" Style="width: 100%;"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Bill Date</label>
                            <div class="input-group margin input-group-sm">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtBDate" runat="server" CssClass="form-control form-control-sm" TabIndex="1" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
                                <ajax:CalendarExtender ID="ce1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtBDate" Format="dd-MM-yyyy" />
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <a href="JavaScript:clearText('<%=txtBDate.ClientID %>')" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm btn-flat"><span class="fa fa-times"></span></a>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Name</label>
                            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtcname" runat="server" CssClass="form-control form-control-sm" TabIndex="2" CausesValidation="True" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hfCustomerId" runat="server" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Phone</label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtcmobile" runat="server" CssClass="form-control form-control-sm" TabIndex="3" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Address</label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtcaddress" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" TabIndex="6" CssClass="form-control form-control-sm"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Lorry Freight</label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLorryFreight" runat="server" TabIndex="6" CssClass="form-control form-control-sm"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Remarks</label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtRemarks" runat="server" TabIndex="6" CssClass="form-control form-control-sm" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Total Amount</label>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server" CssClass="form-control form-control-sm lblTotal" Text="0" ForeColor="Blue" BackColor="#DEE2E6"></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Payable Amount</label>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblPayableAmt" runat="server" CssClass="form-control form-control-sm lblPayableAmt" Text="0" ForeColor="Blue" BackColor="#DEE2E6"></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Paid Amount</label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPaidAmt" runat="server" CssClass="form-control form-control-sm txtPaidAmt" OnTextChanged="CalculatePaidAmount" AutoPostBack="true" TabIndex="8" ForeColor="Blue" Text="0"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Balance Amount</label>
                            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                <label id="lblBalAmt" runat="server" class="form-control form-control-sm lblBalAmt" style="color: red; background-color: #DEE2E6;">0</label>
                                <span class="input-group-append">
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkPayable" runat="server" OnClick="ReCalculate" CssClass="btn btn-outline-success btn-flat" Text="" TabIndex="9" CausesValidation="false"><i class="fa fa-sync"></i></asp:LinkButton>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And my aspx.cs code:

```
protected void GetBillDetails()
{
    string query = "select * from estimates where bno='" + Request.QueryString["bno"].ToString() + "';";
    grdPurchaseBill.DataSource = dal.GetData(query);
    grdPurchaseBill.DataBind();        
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cm.constring))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        {
            using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    txtBDate.Text = dr["bill_date"].ToString();
                    txtcname.Text = dr["name"].ToString();
                    txtcmobile.Text = dr["mobileno"].ToString();
                    txtcaddress.Text = dr["address"].ToString();
                    txtLorryFreight.Text = dr["lorry_freight"].ToString();
                    txtRemarks.Text = dr["remarks"].ToString();
                    lblTotal.Text = dr["grand_total"].ToString();
                    lblPayableAmt.Text = dr["payable_amount"].ToString();
                    txtPaidAmt.Text = dr["paid_amount"].ToString();
                    lblBalAmt.InnerText = dr["balance_amount"].ToString();
                    bno.InnerText = Request.QueryString["bno"].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        con.Close();
    }
}


protected void ReCalculate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal PayableAmount = 0, PaidAmount = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPaidAmt.Text) ? Convert.ToDecimal(txtPaidAmt.Text) : 0, NetWeight = 0, SubTotal = 0, NetAmount = 0;
    foreach (GridViewRow Row in grdPurchaseBill.Rows)
    {
        TextBox txtProduct = Row.FindControl("txtProduct") as TextBox;
        TextBox txtWeight = Row.FindControl("txtWeight") as TextBox;
        TextBox txtBags = Row.FindControl("txtBags") as TextBox;
        TextBox txtShortagePercent = Row.FindControl("txtShortagePercent") as TextBox;
        TextBox txtShortage = Row.FindControl("txtShortage") as TextBox;
        TextBox txtNetWeight = Row.FindControl("txtNetWeight") as TextBox;
        TextBox txtRate = Row.FindControl("txtRate") as TextBox;
        TextBox txtSubTotal = Row.FindControl("txtSubTotal") as TextBox;
        TextBox txtHamali = Row.FindControl("txtHamali") as TextBox;
        TextBox txtHamaliAmount = Row.FindControl("txtHamaliAmount") as TextBox;
        TextBox txtDriverCommission = Row.FindControl("txtDriverCommission") as TextBox;
        TextBox txtNetAmount = Row.FindControl("txtNetAmount") as TextBox;
        Control txtShortagePercent_ctrl = Row.FindControl("txtShortagePercent") as TextBox;
        if (txtShortagePercent_ctrl != null)
        {
            txtShortage.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(txtWeight.Text) - (Convert.ToDecimal(txtWeight.Text) - (Convert.ToDecimal(txtWeight.Text)) * (Convert.ToDecimal(txtShortage.Text) / 100))).ToString("#0.00");
            //txtHamaliAmount.Text = (calculateHamali(Convert.ToDecimal(txtWeight.Text), Convert.ToDecimal(txtHamali.Text))).ToString("#0.00");

            decimal TotalHamali = Convert.ToDecimal(txtHamali.Text) > 0 ? ((Convert.ToDecimal(txtWeight.Text) / 100) * Convert.ToDecimal(txtHamali.Text)) : 0;
            NetAmount += ((Convert.ToDecimal(txtSubTotal.Text) - TotalHamali));// + Convert.ToDecimal(txtDriverCommission.Text)
            txtNetAmount.Text = NetAmount.ToString("#0.00");
            txtHamaliAmount.Text = TotalHamali.ToString("#0.00");

            NetWeight += (Convert.ToDecimal(txtWeight.Text) - (Convert.ToDecimal(txtWeight.Text) * Convert.ToDecimal(txtShortage.Text) / 100));
            txtNetWeight.Text = NetWeight.ToString("#0.00");
            txtShortage.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(txtWeight.Text) - (Convert.ToDecimal(txtWeight.Text) - (Convert.ToDecimal(txtWeight.Text) * Convert.ToDecimal(txtShortage.Text) / 100))).ToString();

            SubTotal += (Convert.ToDecimal(txtNetWeight.Text) * Convert.ToDecimal(txtRate.Text));
            txtSubTotal.Text = SubTotal.ToString("#0.00");

            TextBox totamt = Row.FindControl("txtNetAmount") as TextBox;
            PayableAmount += Convert.ToDecimal(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(totamt.Text) ? totamt.Text : "0");
        }
    }
    lblTotal.Text = (PayableAmount).ToString("#0.00");
    lblPayableAmt.Text = (PayableAmount - Convert.ToDecimal(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLorryFreight.Text) ? txtLorryFreight.Text : "0")).ToString("#0.00");
    lblBalAmt.InnerText = (PaidAmount > 0 ? Convert.ToDecimal(lblPayableAmt.Text) - PaidAmount : Convert.ToDecimal(lblPayableAmt.Text) - 0).ToString("#0.00");
}
```

Comment: A SQL Server is a multi-thread server and query does not come back in same order every time unless you use an order by to sort the results.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @jdweng but the problem I'm facing is not with the query. It is with the re-calculation after changing the values in the GridView.

Comment: Well don't you save it back to the database and then do another query?  The 2nd query order may not be the same order as first query and may not be the same order as what was put into the dataview.

Comment: Nope, I'm using a query to fetch the bill details here. Once the bill details are fetched, the user can change the values, and then it is calculated again after everything is done, I update the details in the database.

Comment: Well, if the user makes edits or changes? Then your recalucalte routine looks ok (it operates from the GV. But your routine GetBill details DOES NOT. So, the only way this could be messing up is if you not saving the data in the GV before calling GetBill details. The other possible is that you are re-loading the GV on post-backs. You should only EVER load the grid in page load  with if (!isPostBack) then load gv. After that, you can't re-bind the GV, else you lose your changes.

Comment: I'm not losing any data from GV, there is a miscalculation taking place here